# Highlight selected element / Redirect user from login page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on simple insert/edit page with login, and had some questions that I couldn't figure out by my self.

1)
[image]

Just like the image above, when the user clicks one of the list on the right side, it highlights the selected one, and pre-populates the data from it on left form.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contacts") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $company = $row['eyo_company_name'];
    $id = $row['con_id'];
    $editLinks .= "\n\t<a href=\"edit.php?id=$id\">$company</a><br>";
}
```

this is how I brought the list out from the database, but I have no idea how to add b tag on selected $company.

2) I have a separate login page, and user will be forced to login before insert / edit page.
If user is directed to login page from insert page, it will redirect to insert after successful login.
If from edit page, it will redirect to edit page.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['8cd97832a4fe'])){

}
else{
    header("Location:login.php?ref=insert.php"); //on insert.php
    header("Location:login.php?ref=edit.php");   //on edit.php
}
```

I have this code block on insert and edit php, so that when user is directed to login page, it can detect where the user is directed from.

```
    if(isset($_POST['loginsubmit'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $ref = $GET_['ref'];

    if(($username == $username_good) && (password_verify($password, $pw_enc))){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['8cd97832a4fe'] = session_id();
        if($ref == 'insert.php'){
            header("Location:insert.php");
        }
        elseif ($ref == 'edit.php'){
            header("Location:edit.php");
        }
        else {
            header("Location:index.php");
        }
```

this is what I currently have in my login.php, but it would only direct me to index.php.

Any help would be much appreciated, and Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your GET variable is typed `$ref = $GET_['ref'];` instead of `$_GET['ref']`

Second observation, `session_start()` should be the first line on your script before any code.

Third Observation,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['8cd97832a4fe'])){
  }
else{
  header("Location:login.php?ref=insert.php"); //on insert.php
  header("Location:login.php?ref=edit.php");   //on edit.php
}
```

You're using multiple headers on your else block.

Comment: I just combined two php pages in one else block for better visual understanding. In my actual php, insert.php and edit.php have one header each that belongs to them.